# Arduino: undefined reference to `Class::attribute'

Tags: c++, arduino, static, arduino-c++

I am developing a library `Button` to handle some functions of buttons and a class `ButtonManager` handling the query of the states of those buttons. I don't want to have to create an object for the `ButtonManager` class so I figured I had to use the `static` keyword for every attribute and method. In addition I am using a third party library to handle timer interrupts which needs a static function as a parameter.
When I try to compile my code, I get the `undefined reference to 'ButtonManager::head'` error.

My `ButtonManager.h` looks like this:

```
#ifndef BUTTON_MANAGER_H
#define BUTTON_MANAGER_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Button.h"
#include "TimerOne.h"


struct ButtonListItem {
  Button* button;
  ButtonListItem* next;
};

class ButtonManager {
  public:
    static ButtonListItem* head = NULL;
    static void begin();
    static void addButton(Button* newButton);
    static void handleButtons();
};
#endif
```

And the `ButtonManager.cpp` file looks like this:

```
#include "ButtonManager.h"

void ButtonManager::begin() {
  Timer1.initialize(100000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(ButtonManager::handleButtons); // handleButtons every 0.1 seconds
}

void ButtonManager::addButton(Button *newButton) {
  ButtonListItem* link = new ButtonListItem;

  link->button = newButton;
  link->next = ButtonManager::head;

  ButtonManager::head = link;
}

void ButtonManager::handleButtons() {
  ButtonListItem* buttonPtr = ButtonManager::head;

  while (buttonPtr != NULL) {
    buttonPtr->button->handleButton();
    buttonPtr = buttonPtr->next;
  }
}
```

I really don't get what is wrong about this implementation. Is it even the right approach?
I'd appreciate any help and tips how to improve my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static ButtonListItem* head = NULL;
```

If you want to use `static` data members you must also define them. Declaration of such a member is not a definition.

Put this line at the top of your *.cpp* file (below `#include`):

```
ButtonListItem* ButtonManager::head = NULL;
```

You may need to also remove `= NULL` from the declaration in the header. Initialization should be done with the definition.

---

As for other things you should provide some way to **clear** the list of buttons. Currently there is no way to de-allocate memory allocated with:

```
ButtonListItem* link = new ButtonListItem;
```

(and possibly also memory occupied by the `Button`s themselves if no other party is to own that memory). Whenever you use `new` there should be corresponding `delete`. And even though for your application it may not matter (static `head` lives till the end of the execution) this is a good practice to apply proper de-allocation always.

Comment: That was quite an easy fix, thank you. And thank you for the advice to use a `delete` for the buttons in order to write better code.